# Create Kafka topic requirements?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have data (orders) that can be grouped by countries, cities.

Could I create over 100 topics with names of countries and billion topic with city names?

Which requirements for topic presents?

Could you demonstrate a good topic usage?

Comment: Please tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve and about its domain (orders). I am confident this will help answering your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Could I create over 100 topics with names of countries and billion
> topic with city names?

1. Creating too many topics isn't a good design because it will be difficult to maintain them.
2. Information like countries, cities etc don't change that often and is not streaming data. So, storing them in a database would make more sense than storing them in a topic.
   It could make *sense* storing them in the topic if it is combined with orders i.e. orders are keyed by *country*, *city* etc which may be done using `map()` in Kafka streams.

> Could you demonstrate a good topic usage?

Because orders is a streaming data, new orders will be added, changed etc, you can have a topic called `orders` where the key will be `order_id` and the value will be an `Order` object where the `Order` object contains properties such as `country`, `city` etc.

Now, you can consume this topic and store the data in different ways:

1. Maintain a data structure like table or map (persistent or in-memory), of the country and its corresponding `Order` objects (or) `order_id`s using which you can get the order objects.

   Note that since there can be many orders per country, the data structure should be something like country and a list of orders.
2. Much simple, is to just store the orders data directly into an RBDMS as a table with `order_id` as primary key and the `Order` object mapped to a database table. Then using SQL or ORM framework, you can query them.

Streaming Kafka data (topics) can also be aggregated, grouped, joined, can be put in a table (persistent or in-memory) etc using Kafka streams.

You can take look at some [Kafka streams examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples#examples-apps).

You may also want to look at [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/) that allows you to have SQL on top of Kafka streams.

Comment: What if I need to send orders to specific client (app mobile)? For example send order which has country USA and Ohio city. Where I should filter this? Using streams?

Comment: Is it not good ideo to create own topic for each customer?

Comment: You can filter using Kafka streams and write the data to a topic or store them in a table. But if you want to perform any *queries*, it could be better to use RDBMS. Also, creating a topic per customer is not good idea, it is like a creating one *database table* per customer. You certainly want a customer record to be a *row* but not a table itself.

Comment: Thank you, one sub-question please, lets imaging I filter data using stream and put data to topic.  How specific customer (mobile app) can retrive message assignied only for him?

Comment: You can create a table with that `user_id` as key and use interactive queries to retrieve his/her info using that id.

Comment: "Information like countries, cities etc … is not streaming data. So, storing them in a database would make more sense than storing them in a topic." This is completely untrue - it is events that creates them, and having that information in a topic means you can rebuild state (or populate a database if you want) at any time you want.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt What I meant was, that countries data is *static* i.e. countries are fixed and they are not generated by user or any event, but an event contains a country, city etc. So, just maintaining countries and cities without anything in the topic is pointless, unless you are storing the *orders* "keyed" by country, city etc in a topic.

Comment: I still disagree. You may well have country data (name, geo fence, dialling codes, flag, etc etc) that you want to use in apps, enrich events, and so on. Storing it in a topic is useful.

Comment: If we are storing it in the topic, I suppose we have to create a `globalktable` for the *static country data* topic and then perform join with the orders topic, i.e. creating a global store (persistent or otherwise) which is more or less like a database, isn't it? The countries topic here which is just used for constructing the global store may as well have been in db itself. *make more sense* doesn't mean "it is only right*, it does *accept* other possibility too. :)